# XML::LibXML converted é to &#xE9;

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have a test.xml file which contains the following content:

```
<div value="éclair">éclair</div>
```

I'm using the following perl code to extract and print it:

```perl
use strict;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::Reader;
use utf8;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

open my $fh, "<", "test.xml";

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(IO => $fh, recover => 1, suppress_errors => 1, huge => 1000000000);


while ($reader->read) {
    next unless $reader->nodeType == XML::LibXML::Reader->XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT;
    next unless $reader->name eq "div";
    my $html = $reader->readOuterXml;
    my $doc = $parser->load_xml(string => $html);

    print $doc->toString() . "\n";

}
```

But this print out:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div value="&#xE9;clair">&#xE9;clair</div>
```

The `é` character has been encoded to `&#xE9;`

Is there a way to avoid this encoding process? or how can I decode `&#xE9;` to `é` in perl?